# Media field attachment preview image is full-sized instead of thumbnail-sized

Tags: media-library

I have content management sites (Sitecore 10.2.1) in 3 different environments. On my non-production sites, my image media library items show reasonably sized attachment previews such that I can easily view the whole image:

[image: image size is good]

Note the small image and small network requests. If I download the image, it is the full size (10.3 MB), which is good.

However, on my production site, the attachment preview image is huge:

[image: image size is huge]

In both cases, the item does have dimensions specified:

[image: image dimensions]

I am not aware of any relevant configuration differences between the different environments.

I inspected the network requests and found that the same URL is being called across the environments:

`/sitecore/shell/Applications/-/media/28a55f89466648d99cd911ac7aa001f4.ashx?bc=white&db=master&h=128&mw=640&thn=1&vs=1&ts=10c8c8d6-9b4a-4874-ae02-c444286c9ade&udi=1`

When I navigate directly to it on my non-production sites, the `h=128&mw=640` params are honored --  however, my production site returns the full sized image.

Therefore, the issue can be partially narrowed down to a difference in handling of: `/sitecore/shell/Applications/-/media/28a55f89466648d99cd911ac7aa001f4.ashx?h=128&mw=640`

Looking at the logs, I do see this error:

`Could not run the 'getMediaStream' pipeline for '/sitecore/media library/....'. Original media data will be used.`

With the stack trace:

```
Exception: System.OutOfMemoryException
Message: Out of memory.
Source: System.Drawing
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttrs, DrawImageAbort callback, IntPtr callbackData)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr)
   at Sitecore.ImageLib.Resizer.ResizeAny(Bitmap image, Size imageSize, Size frameSize, Color frameColor, Boolean preserveResolution, InterpolationMode interpolationMode, CompositingMode compositingMode, PixelOffsetMode pixelOffsetMode)
   at Sitecore.ImageLib.Resizer.Resize(Bitmap bitmap, ResizeOptions options, ImageFormat format, InterpolationMode interpolationMode)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageEffectsResize.ResizeImageStream(Stream inputStream, TransformationOptions options, ImageFormat outputFormat)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageEffects.TransformImageStream(Stream inputStream, TransformationOptions options, ImageFormat outputFormat)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ThumbnailGenerator.GetImageStream(Stream inputStream, TransformationOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ImageThumbnailGenerator.GetStream(MediaData mediaData, TransformationOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaData.GetThumbnailStream(TransformationOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.ThumbnailProcessor.Process(GetMediaStreamPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object argument)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Media.Media.GetStreamFromPipeline(MediaOptions options, Boolean& canBeCached)
```

There are similar questions to this on SSE, but not with this particular stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Clearing the MediaCache folder and restarting the site fixed the issue permanently; a restart was not enough. Clearly there were files in the media cache that were causing the `getMediaStream` threads to run out of memory. The exact cause is not cleared, but presumably it was due to corrupt files.

**Original Answer**

Restarting the App Service resolved the issue. My guess is that this was a byproduct of a recent Azure outage.

Below is a chart of the app service memory usage over the period and after the restart. You can see the memory usage drop down right after the reset, but the memory usage never appeared to be anywhere near the limit (7GB) during the period of the issue occurring, so it is still unclear as to why this exception was being thrown.

[image: memory usage]

Comment: Plot twist: the issue is persisting.